# How do I redirect the output of grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2?

Tags: redirect

I'm working in a command line-only environment, so I'm used to redirecting output to text files. In this instance, I need to set a password for GRUB2, but trying to use redirection with the corresponding utility makes it stop printing to the screen, so I am not presented with a way to enter my desired password. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Pipe the output to `tee`, which prints its input to `stdout` and optionally also to multiple files:

```
grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 | tee out
```

```
% grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 | tee out
Enter password: 
Reenter password: 
PBKDF2 hash of your password is grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.CF99115D7DE57D065ECA4420F829FACD1FEDDD1C08ACFDDEBBB6C2948DECECCA37DEBE4F0FB37FC8CAE385A1A440663225AFB2E79B4E69557F2F9BD13AB6E586.5D5AA1A70E60CF1C09AB6B9EF831996E3F60DF7B85ADE364C7E469DC88BAAE3D8DE0F1C2A5E60267170580564AF2A36DADA663DE2DF4407562A90FEAC7E78262
% cat out
Enter password: 
Reenter password: 
PBKDF2 hash of your password is grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.CF99115D7DE57D065ECA4420F829FACD1FEDDD1C08ACFDDEBBB6C2948DECECCA37DEBE4F0FB37FC8CAE385A1A440663225AFB2E79B4E69557F2F9BD13AB6E586.5D5AA1A70E60CF1C09AB6B9EF831996E3F60DF7B85ADE364C7E469DC88BAAE3D8DE0F1C2A5E60267170580564AF2A36DADA663DE2DF4407562A90FEAC7E78262
```

Comment: That includes the input in the output file, which is a security risk.

Comment: @Melab No it doesn't, check the output in the update i made to the answer

Comment: Ah! You are correct. I had already tried tee with different commands and it hadn't worked before.

Answer (score 1):

`grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` writes the prompt and the encrypted password to stdout, so even if the prompt isn't visible, you can still type your password in, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type it again, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again:

```
$ grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 > bar
$ cat bar
Enter password: 
Reenter password: 
PBKDF2 hash of your password is grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.40D06FD775735FA1E05AA2A732A588F79493CF7071718EFE99DEFFF06706421849716160D668D90D29139AD1A2537862DFCD6D1D172AEC7DF6552D948C472315.93544ED4795D377AB1C7FC40BA2079872F7AF19440931A7A0A71D7441C6EB563AE5438B60050F0573CF55FBD2FF0BF3ACE4811898794DD589E0BF4F184C9996C
```

Comment: That's not a very neat or user-friendly solution.

Comment: @Melab File a bug report.